# Matrices equation with one unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us consider following equation:
$$
2X^2+2X=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 5 & 3 \\
-2 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -4 &  -3
\end{array} \right). 
$$
I have to show that there is no real matrix which satisfy my equation.
I consider three diffrent way to do this.

1. Direct method. Let $$X=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
   g & h & i
   \end{array} \right).
   $$ Then we can write euqation in equivalent form $X(X+I)=\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
   -1 & 5 & 3 \\
   -2 & 1 & 2 \\
   0 & -4 &  -3
   \end{array} \right)$, and we obtain system of nonlinear equations
   $$
   \left\{ \begin{array}{llll}
   a^2+a+bd+cg=-\frac{1}{2} \\
   ab+be+b+ch=\frac{5}{2}\\
   ac+bf+ci+c=\frac{3}{2}\\
   da+d+ed+fg=-1\\
   db+e^2+e+fh=\frac{1}{2}\\
   dc+ef+fi+f=1\\
   ga+g+hd+ig=0\\
   gb+he+h+ih=-2\\
   gc+hf+i^2+i=-\frac{3}{2}
   \end{array} \right. 
   $$
   I was trying to deal with it, but it was impossible to solve for me (I can not use Mathematica, Matlab,etc)
2. Determinant method. From the fact, that $X(X+I)=\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
   -1 & 5 & 3 \\
   -2 & 1 & 2 \\
   0 & -4 &  -3
   \end{array} \right)$, we have that $\det X \det (X+I)=-\frac{11}{8}$, and then using direct method i was traing to write formula for $\det (X+I)$ in terms of $\det X$, but here also appear formulas,to difficult for me to interpret it.
3. My last idea to solve is to use formula for inverse matrix $3\times3$  ($X$ is invertible, which is consequence of the fact, that $\det X\neq 0$) and from relation $X+I=X^{-1}\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
   -1 & 5 & 3 \\
   -2 & 1 & 2 \\
   0 & -4 &  -3
   \end{array} \right)$ we also obtain system of equations, which is much more complicated, that this previous one.

I would be grateful if you give me some hints.

Comment: maybe it would be useful to use the fact that a real square matrix on odd dimension have at least one eigenvalue and try to see what are the eigenvalues of the given matrix in the RHS of the equation

Comment: One eigenvalue od RHS is real, and two are complex. But what does it mean for matrix $X$?

Comment: It feels a bit pedestrian, but if $Y=2X^2+2X$ then $2Y+I=4X^2+4X+I=(2X+I)^2$. So that turns it into showing that there's no real square-root of $2Y+I$.

Comment: @akap if $x$ is an eigenvector of $X$ then we get the equation $(2a ^2+2a)x =Yx$, where $a$ is the corresponding eigenvalue, so it would be enough to show that $Y$ doesn't have an eigenvalue of the form $2a^2+2a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. You can simplify the form of the matrix in the RHS before to do any calculation using some change of basis

Comment: I solved your system in paragraph $1$ with *Mathematica* and got only complex solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were a real matrix $X$ satisfying ...
Scalar-multiply the given equation with $2$ and add the identity matrix to get
$$(2X+\mathbb 1)^2 \;=\; \begin{pmatrix} -1& 10& 6\\
-4& 3& 4\\
0& -8& -5 \end{pmatrix}$$
Apply the determinant which produces $\,-25\,$ on the RHS, hence a contradiction because the resulting square on the LHS cannot get negative if $X$ is a real matrix.

Comment: Trace of RHS $<0$, but when matrix in LHS is positive-semidefinite, it should be $\geq0$. So we obtain contradiction. Where can I find proof of the fact, that for real matrix $A$ matrix $A^2$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: This may be the point where my answer breaks down because it is simply not true.
Just regarding $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&1&0\\ -1&  0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ ...

Comment: A stab at completing this approach: If $X$ is real, then so is $2X+1$ and thus the characteristic polynomial of $2X+1$ has real coefficients. Thus its eigenvalues must be real or in complex conjugate pairs. Therefore the eigenvalues of $(2X+1)^2$ must either be positive or in complex-conjugate pairs...but the above matrix has a negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @Semiclassical The matrix in my previous comment is a general counter-example to show that the statement
"whenever $A$ is real, then $A^2\geq 0$" is false. Which invalidates my answer as it currently stands.

Comment: Well, note that your counterexample has roots $0,\pm i$. It thus has no negative roots. I think the problem arises when you have a negative root of odd multiplicity, since there's no way to obtain them by squaring real numbers or complex-conjugate pairs of roots.